# How to manipulate a pandas DataFrame of a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataset

Hey guys so I have been using data from a csv file and have put that data into a pandas DataFrame. The original data has 6 columns and one of the columns called 'actions' is a list of dictionaries. I've made a temp dataframe by doing something like this -

> temp = pd.DataFrame(dataframe['actions'])

And this is one of the example rows in that new dataframe -

> [{"E": 24, "action": "views"}, {"F": 22, "action": "noise"}, {"H": 39, "action": "conversions"}]

I'm not sure how to manipulate this data. I want to get a list of instances where say 'E' has a higher value where it's 'action' is 'views' over when 'E' has an 'action' that is 'conversions' for instance. The keys in subsequent rows in the dataframe aren't present in every row.

edit - Intended output isn't necessarily another DataFrame but likely just a python list of single letters keys that fit the criteria. To be more explicit I want to search through the whole dataframe to compare instances when the actions are of two specific types and then comparing the numerical value. So if my conditions are only if action are 'views' and 'conversions' it would look for instances of the same single letter key like

> "E" {"E": 24, "action": "views"} and {"E": 45, "action": "conversions"}

or for

> "A" {"A": 12, "action": "views"} and {"A": 28, "action": "conversions"}.

Which of course can appear on different rows in the data frame. So at the end of my proposed function it would return a list of single letter strings where the conditions are met.

Here's what a sample of the df looks like -

> 0,"[{""E"": 24, ""action"": ""views""}, {""F"": 22, ""action"": ""noise""}, {""H"": 39, ""action"": ""conversions""}]"
>
> 1,"[{""B"": 79, ""action"": ""clicks""}, {""H"": 3, ""action"": ""conversions""}, {""G"": 68, ""action"": ""junk""}]"
>
> 2,"[{""E"": 10, ""action"": ""views""}, {""D"": 41, ""action"": ""views""}, {""J"": 52, ""action"": ""conversions""}]"
>
> 3,"[{""A"": 47, ""action"": ""clicks""}, {""E"": 93, ""action"": ""junk""}, {""D"": 54, ""action"": ""views""}]"
>
> 4,"[{""H"": 16, ""action"": ""views""}, {""G"": 41, ""action"": ""conversions""}, {""C"": 80, ""action"": ""junk""}]"

Hopeful example outcome

> ['H']

because 'H'in row 0 has a dictionary  {"H": 39, "action": "conversions"} which has a numerical value larger than row 4 which has {"H": 16, "action": "views"} since we're looking for where the 'conversions' action has a larger value than the 'views' action of the same single letter key 'H'.

Comment: Hi @animusdx. I'm not sure about what you are trying to accomplish. Can you be more specific? (i.e., can you provide the output that you would have?)

Comment: BTW, I have know idea what you mean.  Read [mcve] and consider [edit]-ing your question accordingly.

Comment: I edited the original post to make a bit more sense hopefully.

Comment: It would help if you posted the df, or at least make up a df that is similar, and show what your expected results would be for that df (as in knowing what conditions your looking for)